# python request give <Response [503]>

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, python-requests

So I am making a comic books downloader/reader(with PyQt5) from the internet and i was good and working but suddenly when I tested the app there was a proplem in the search function in the request code and here is the code

```
url='https://www.comicextra.com/comic-search?key=%s'%self.searchle.text().replace(' ','+')
page = requests.get(url, stream=True)#to get the page of the search results
print(page)
html=bs4.BeautifulSoup(page.text,features="html5lib")#to get the html of the page
srl=html.select('div[class="mb-right"] h3 a')#to get the search results as a list
details=html.select('div[class="mb-right"] div[class="detail"]')#to get the detalis
```

this is part of fucntion of QMainwindow class and when I do print(page) it gives me :Response [503]

I searched about this and they say it is server problem but the thing is the website work just fine(you can check yourself) so is there is any solve to this problem?

Comment: What do the logs say as far as why the server is throwing a 503?

Comment: i didn't get what you asking

Comment: @IslamEssam He's asking if the server logs have any information on a possible error/problem.

Comment: No i don't think it has

Answer (score 0):

`503` is a HTTP Status code for `Service Unavailable`. That might be because the server can't handle the number of requests it's getting.

Comment: No, the system didn't log your request when you sent it. You'll have to retry.